# C++ bind member function with variadic template

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, bind

My example below uses variadic templates to register a function inside a class. Registering a single function works but what about class member functions? I tried std::bind but this expects placeholders which is not an option because I don't know the number of arguments. Is there a simple way doing this in C++11 or am I forced to implement the register function for every amount of arguments?

```
template<typename TReturn, typename... TArgs>
class Func {
    std::function<TReturn (TArgs...)> fn;

    template<typename TFunction, typename TObject>
    bool register(TFunction f, TObject obj){

    }

    bool register(std::function<TReturn (TArgs...)> f){
        fn = f;
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: You won't have much fun calling a function `register` as this identifier is a keyword. more importantly you seem to have two functions with that name and one without implementstion: what do you expect the function to do?

Comment: I forgot to change the names. You are right this won't work. Let's forget about the second function. What I want is to store a class member function inside fn.

Comment: You don't need the separate overload for member functions, the user can use the overload taking the `std::function`, and pass `std::bind(&X::f, obj, args...)` or a suitable functor.

Comment: Thank you for the responses so far. I don't understand how std::bind(&X::f, obj, args...) could help because the exact number of arguments is not known and std::bind for class members need std::placholder when i want to call fn later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a lambda function with the required signature and construct the `std::function` object from it.

```
template<typename TReturn, typename... TArgs>
class Func {
    std::function<TReturn (TArgs...)> fn;

    template<typename TFunction, typename TObject>
    bool Register(TFunction f, TObject obj){
        fn = [obj](TArgs... args){return (obj.*f)(args...);};
        return true;
    }

    bool Register(std::function<TReturn (TArgs...)> f){
        fn = f;
        return true;
    }   
}
```

(Note : [Member function pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions) need to be used with a corresponding object, object reference or a pointer to an object of the appropriate class. If `TObject` is value-like, the member function call syntax would be `(obj.*f)`. If `TObject` is pointer-like, the syntax would be `(obj->*f)`.)

Comment: fn = [&](TArgs... args){return (obj->*f)(args...);}; works but gives a segmentation fault when calling fn. Non class member function works great.

Comment: @Gustavo Change the call to `(obj.*f)(args...)`. The dereference has weaker binding than the call. If you continue to get a seg fault we need a reproducible example.

Comment: This doesn't compile because I give a pointer to the object to the register function.

Comment: @Gustavo Please change the call syntax accordingly. Since the type was named `TObject`, I assumed it was one. If it is a pointer, the right syntax would be `(obj->*f)`.